# How can I put two divs on the same line?

Tags: html

I have 2 divs and I want to align them in the same line. The html code is:

```
<div class="box">
<div class="boxleft"> </div>
<div class="boxright"> </div>
</div>
```

I tried 'float: left;' and 'float: right;' but the background is going crazy, it apears just on ~30px of the height. I tried to put a height('till then I didn't use height in CSS). It didnt' work. I tried 'display: inline-block' too, but without succes.

Thanks.

CSS:

```
.box {
width: 956px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
background: #584231;}

.boxleft {
width: 706px;
margin-right: auto;
border-right: 2px solid black;}

 .boxright {
width: 250px;
margin-left: auto;
float: right;}
```

Comment: `inline-block` ought to work; what's the rest of your CSS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On most modern browsers nowadays `display: table-cell` is the better alternative to floating.

Answer (score 1):

`Float: left` should do the trick depending on the width of the parent `box`and the width of `boxleft` and `boxright`. If the parent `box` has `width: 500px;` and `boxleft` and `boxright`both have `width: 250px; float:left;`. You should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the css properties `float:left` and `clear:both`.

http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_float.asp

Answer (score 1):

I put some colors on each background to make it clear, you're maybe lacking a width and height for each element..

```
.boxleft , .boxright {
    float : left;
    width : 200px;
    height : 100px;
    margin : 10px;
}
.boxleft {
    background : yellow;
}
.boxright {
    background : blue;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/n9mHX/

Comment: You don't need to specify `width` and `height` in order to make `float` work.

Answer (score 0):

You may use

```
display:inline-block;
```

or

```
float
```

or as per latest browser out you may use

```
display: table-cell
```

or you may use

```
clear: both
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're not a "CSS guy", look at http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/. With bootstrap, put two div on the same line is done this way :

```
<div class="row-fluid box">
    <div class="span6 boxleft"></div>
    <div class="span6 boxright"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to clear the floats via clearfix on the parent container.

```
.box {
    width: 956px;
    background: #584231;
}

/* clearfix */
.box:after {
     content: '';
     display: block;
     clear: both;
     visibility: hidden;
     line-height: 0;
     height: 0;
}

.boxleft {
    width: 704px;
    border-right: 2px solid black;
    float: left;
}

.boxright {
    width: 250px;
    float: right;
}
```

The border is adding 2px to your divs width. That's why I specified it with 704px.

Using `inline-block` as `display` for the left and right box should work too.